# GPU to drive three monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu

What do I need to look for in a GPU to ensure it is capable of outputting to three high resolution monitors?

To be clear, I want to drive three monitors whose resolution is greater than 1080p. For example (but not specifically), three Dell Ultrasharp U2713HM monitors, which each do 2560x1440 resolution.

I do **not** want specific GPU recommendations. I want to know what things I need to look for in a graphics card if I want to output to three >1080p monitors.

Comment: How about looking at the specs and sales literature, and ensuring they state that it supports >2 monitors at the resolution you desire? Or is RTFM not a valid solution to this shopping conundrum? ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 that's good in theory, but harder in practice. To take one random graphics card, http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=04G-P4-2649-KR  Now, that has three display interfaces, but no indication if all three can be used at once. And no indication on what the maximum resolution is on the hdmi interface.

Comment: Then that would be one to avoid. ;) Really, I think the only answer is to contact the manufacturer (or an official reseller who knows the cards) and ask them for the missing information you seek. When I worked as/for a reseller, that's what we had to do when customers requested certain features that weren't obvious on the spec sheets provided.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, that may well be the necessary solution to the problem. That's a bit of a shame, I was hoping it'd be a bit more obvious given the spec sheet. Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is the graphic card 'Video Memory' specification.

In graphic cards, it all comes down to a few specs to let you know how good will the card perform.

```
Core clock - measured in MHz (ie.: 742MHz)
**Video Memory** - in MB/GB (ie.: 1280MB or 1GB)
Memory interface - usually in bits (ie.: 320-bit)
Memory clock - in MHz too (ie.: 3800MHz )
```

Core clock is basically the raw performance of the video card; it is the speed at which the card operates and which is also similar to memory clock. In gaming, it is the biggest responsible for high fps output.

Memory Interface is like a communication "channel" used between the core and memory, and the larger this value is, the more data can be exchanged between these two simultaneously. Not the most important, but also plays a fundamental role when it comes to big memory hog systems as it is the case with triple monitor.

So, in your case I would definitely look for the Video Memory specification keeping an eye on memory interface.
The higher this value is, the more pixels it may easily render. Also be sure to watch for the `"Maximum Resolution"` of the card to see if it meets your "2560x1440" requirement.

Comment: I don't believe this is sufficient. Many graphics cards have plenty sufficient video memory but don't have enough output ports, and so couldn't possibly support three monitors.